# What is the simpliest way to apply the same logic on multiple variables instead of writing it out line by line?

Tags: python

If I have a data frame with 10 variables and I need to apply the same logic across on some of variables, what is the best way to simplify the code (like an array function) instead of writing it out line by line like below:

```
#logic 1
df['var1'] = df['var1'].replace(['(S)'], 'NaN')
df['var2'] = df['var1'].replace(['(S)'], 'NaN')
df['var3'] = df['var1'].replace(['(S)'], 'NaN')

#logic 2
df['var1'] = df['var1'].apply(lambda x: x/100)
df['var2'] = df['var2'].apply(lambda x: x/100)
df['var3'] = df['var3'].apply(lambda x: x/100)
```

Comment: That depends on your application.  Typically, an iteration loop over the sequence of variables does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply some action to all the vars in `df`:

```
for var in df:
    df[var].replace(['(S)'], 'NaN')
```

if you want to update only some vars:

```
for var in ('var1', 'var2', 'var3'):
    df[var].replace(['(S)'], 'NaN')
```